# Regex for Detecting words + parenthesis

Tags: regex

In my recent things to do, I am stuck in figuring out regex for reserved words like `IF( foo, bar )`, `ELSE` , `ENDIF`

So what should be the exact regex for things like:"

```
IF( ?a , <, 4 ) // do some things

ELSE // do some things
```

etc.

I need to be able to find the words as the beginning of the string and it should be able to detect those only put in the beginning, thus, strings like this should not be included:

```
//somethings are done here then IF(foo, bar)
```

I tried in http://www.regexr.com/ to use: `/^IF\((\w)\)/` for looking for IF() in strings,  but it's not able to detect the IF() string. Is there something wrong with the expression?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem with your regex is that `\w` expects at least one word, so you should probably try `\w?` which would make the word optional. Are you trying to build some kind of template engine here? Maybe it would be a better idea to use something existing for that...

Comment: some sort of a formula engine that would parse a given formula by the user. I used ^IF\((.*)\)\: instead and added delimiters to ignore additional IF() patterns

Comment: Well maybe you could use an existing script interpreter for this and just feed the user input into that. Depends on your use case, but doing a formula calculator with regex is probably going to be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in general this problem is not a good fit for regex because of nested parentheses and other elements in code.

If your strings are simple you can try `IF[^)]*\)` instead.

This regex will pick the `IF` and any characters that are not the right parenthesis up to the first right parenthesis. However it will fail if you have nested parentheses.

If your regex implementation supports zero length lookahead you can try this:

```
IF.*\)(?=[^)]*$)
```

This will pick the `IF` and all characters up to the last right parenthesis on the string. However this too will fail in case you have a parenthesis in the comment for example.

Answer (score 0):

I used `/^IF\((.*)\)\:/` instead and added delimiters to ignore additional IF() patterns. I also added explicitly looking for the beginning of the string and not in the middle of the string to avoid the second case. I will also follow the same pattern for the other cases that I need.

Thanks SO!